# How to insert a ProcessingInstruction on the second line of a generated XML file?

Tags: php, xml

I got an XML file that is generated for me by a third party website that goes something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results>
  <row></row>
  <row></row>
  <row></row>
</results>
```

I add `ProcessingInstruction`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($url); // $url point to the third party website's generated XML with structure like from above example
$xslt = $dom->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"');
$dom->appendChild($xslt); //adds it to the very end, but needs to go on the second line
```

And end up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results>
  <row></row>
  <row></row>
  <row></row>
</results>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
    <results>
      <row></row>
      <row></row>
      <row></row>
    </results>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert the processing instruction before the root element (the results tag). DOMNode::insertBefore is a bit weird, because you have to call it on the parent element and provide the element you want to insert as the first parameter and the element where you want to insert it before as the second parameter. `$dom->documentElement` references the document root (= results tag).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($url); 
$xslt = $dom->createProcessingInstruction('xml-stylesheet', 'type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"');
$dom->insertBefore($xslt, $dom->documentElement);
echo $dom->saveXML();
```